# Match "word" but not "word (whatever)"?

Tags: regex

I have a string, it can either be "word" or "word (something)". How can I only match "word", but not "word (something)"?

Comment: Does it have to be in parenthesis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the regex flavor, you can probably use a negative lookahead. Like this:

```
word(?! \(something\))
```

Just checks to make sure there isn't a space and the word something after the matched word.

Oh, and if you have JUST the word "word" in the string, you could do:

```
^word$
```

which makes sure that `word` is the start `(^)` and the end `($)` of the string.

But if you had JUST the word "word" in the string, you could have just done

```
wordString == "word"; // or wordVariable in place of "word", or whatever
```

Comment: make that `word(?! \(something\))`

Comment: @m.buettner was doing it as you made the comment :) lol just forgot to put it in there

Answer (score 1):

you can use `^word$`.

here ^ sign indicates start of string and $ indicates end of string

so it will match to "word" only ..

Answer (score 0):

From the python manual:

`(?!...)`

This is a negative lookahead assertion. Matches characters if `...` doesn’t match next character set.

For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that you phrased the string you do not want to match differently in the title and the actual question, I am assuming that you do not mean the literal strings "whatever" and "something".

Provided that you are using a regex flavour that supports negative lookahead, this should work:

```
word(?! \([^)]*\))
```