# How to say "match this word, except if it is surrounded by <something>"?

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
This MUST should be caught, but not this one **MUST** because it is between **
```

The idea is that I will be running a search/replace on some files, several times, and I would like the replace to be idempotent. This is because some `MUST` may have already been changed into `**MUST**` and I do not want to end up with `******MUST******` after a few runs.

To do that I tried to build a regex that says *"match `MUST` but not if it is surrounded by `**`"*:

```
(?!\(\*\*\))MUST(?!\(\*\*\))
```

(inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584415/match-word-but-not-word-whatever), [regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/sd0OwT/1)).

This however matches both `MUST`.

Comment: Where/how are you going to do the replacement?

Comment: @VLAZ: I will probably write a Python script (or a Go program), but I am open to any suggestions. This is not something critical, rather a way to make sure that some documentation is more or less consistent.

Comment: Maybe `(?<!\*\*)MUST(?!\*\*)` or `\b(?<!\*\*)MUST\b(?!\*\*)`? It will work in Python but not in Go.

Comment: `(?<!\*\*\)MUST(?!\*\*\)` should work

Comment: OK, just making sure you have access to backreferences. You can use [The Best Regex Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) (scroll to **The Best Regex Trick Ever (at last!)** to skip the preamble if you're not interested) - you can match `\*\*MUST\*\*|(MUST)` and replace only when you have a group match with `**$1**`

Comment: @anubhava Splitting hairs, but let's just say that `***MUST***` with _three_ stars on each side _should_ be targeted for replacement.  The problem with the single regex approach is that it might open up some edge cases (which admittedly may be very unlikely).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: May be `(?<!\S)\bMUST\b(?!\S)` is better in that case

Comment: `(?<!\S)\bMUST\b(?!\S)` is the same as `(?<!\S)MUST(?!\S)`, as whitespace boundaries are word boundaries, too.

Comment: WoJ, please just confirm if you want to find `MUST` in a string like `This **is something I MUST replace**, too.`. Or, if you want to only avoid matching if `**` enclose the word immediately on the left and right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you - I did not think about that case. It is not likely it will happen so if this is complicated to handle it I will find another way. Ultimately this is Markdown so `This **is something I MUST replace**, too` should stay as it (as it is already bolded). This is a good catch, thanks.

Comment: You simply should use a markdown parser, or write a parsing code for that. You can't do that safely with regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the MD will be parsed afterward. My problem is that I get some docs from various places, some have highlighted what they were supposed to highlight, some not. I wanted to make a coherent set of docs by adding the highlights where they should be. I also needed to match with regex open HTML tags except XHTML self-contained tags - but that's another question.

Comment: Oh, please, [do not ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: incredible, there is an answer to everything in SO :) (I got reminded of Tony the Pony a few days ago  when reading a Meta discussion about the new usage of native fonts in SE, when one of the strong requirements was to not break this answer :))

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a way to do this using pure regex, but if you have access to Python, then you may use `re.sub` along with a callback function as follows:

```py
inp = "This MUST should be caught, but not this one **MUST** because it is between **"
output = re.sub(r'\*\*MUST\*\*|\bMUST\b', lambda x: '**MUST**' if x.group() == '**MUST**' else 'MUST NOT', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
This MUST NOT should be caught, but not this one **MUST** because it is between **
```

The strategy here is that we simply match *both* `**MUST**` and `MUST` (the latter as a standalone word).  Then, in the callback function, we no-op for the `**MUST**` matches, but selectively replace with `MUST NOT` for the standalone `MUST` matches.

Comment: Easier to make your desired match a capture group `|\b(MUST)\b'` then you can check if there was any capture and replace just that. Any of the other alterations are irrelevant, so you can add as many as you want like `\*\*MUST\*\*|""MUST""|--MUST--|` etc. that you want to discard.

Comment: Meh.  The logic I have above is very clear, and using a capture group trick, while perhaps saving some code, makes it more complex.

Comment: Beside what @VLAZ mentions, in cases where a simple string replacement pattern can be used (it looks like it is the case here) the string replacement should be preferred, as using a lambda/method in the replacement has a certain performance penalty.

Answer (score -1):

In this case instead of skipping the `*` characters, you can always replace them, so multiple replaces would still result in the same string. You can do a straight forward

Search: `\**\b(MUST)\b\**`
Replace: `**$1**`

In pretty much any tool you want including most text editors. Search for all instances of **MUST** as a separate word possibly surrounded with any amount of asterisks, then replace the whole thing with ****MUST****.

[Regex 101 demo of the replacement](https://regex101.com/r/d976uY/1)

This does mean that if you have *MUST* or similar you will also match them but if your delimiters are expected to be unique, then replacing them every is still an idempotent operation.

Runnable demo in JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector("#replace")
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    const container = document.querySelector("#text");
    const text = container.value;
    
    container.value = text.replace(
      /\**\b(MUST)\b\**/g,
      "**$1**"
    );
  });
```

```css
#text {
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">This MUST should be caught, but not this one **MUST** because it is between ** but MUSTANG or WORDMUST are not replaced</textarea>
<br />
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
```